Wordpress Texonomy Custom Slug
// Register Taxonomy Specialties
function bestdoc_register_specialties_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Specialties', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'bestdoc' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Specialty', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'bestdoc' ),),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove specialties', 'bestdoc' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used specialties', 'bestdoc' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'No specialties found', 'bestdoc' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Specialties', 'bestdoc' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'hierarchical'      => true,  // Set to true if you want parent-child relationships
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 
            'slug' => '', // Empty slug to avoid adding 'specialties' in the URL
            'with_front' => false, // Avoid adding front/base of the site URL
            'hierarchical' => true // This allows term hierarchy in URL (e.g., /parent-term/child-term)
        ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'specialties', array( 'locations' ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'bestdoc_register_specialties_taxonomy', 0 );

In this case my URL now example.com/specialties/slug/
How can I make it example.com/slug/
I try 'slug' => '/' It's changing the URL but getting a 404 Error
